# typescript: import jspm libraries

Tags: angularjs, typescript, systemjs, jspm

So most examples I found on importing jspm packages to typescript assumed that I wanted to use Systemjs to load and interpret them in the browser. However, I would rather like to use `tsc` to build commonjs modules and only import the js code, since it seems to me to be the more general and error-resistent approach to me.

So my directory structure looks like this:

```
src/index.ts
jspm_packages/...
config.js
tsconfig.json
```

With tsconfig having the following content:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "rootDir": "src",
    "outDir": "target/app",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "declaration": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "jspm_packages",
    "node_modules",
    "typings",
    "target"
  ]
}
```

For testing purposes, I installed angular 2 with `jspm install npm:angular2` and tried to import it in my `index.ts` via `import { bootstrap } from 'angular2/platform/browser';`

When running `tsc`, I get the error

```
src/index.ts(1,27): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'angular2/platform/browser'.
```

Now I wonder, can I make jspm-packages known to typescript? I feel like I tried it all, removing the jspm_packages from the tsconfig exclude list, switching to node module resolution or systemjs module generation. Maybe I just haven't found the right combination. Any hints on what to try next?

Comment: The first line from the jspm site is "_jspm is a package manager for the SystemJS universal module loader, built on top of the dynamic ES6 module loader_". I don't think using jspm without system.js is the right approach here.

Answer (score 2):

I am also struggling with this same issue and after some research, I learned that there no good solutions to allow this as of yet.

Workarounds:

A) You can duplicate your dependencies and install it with npm. tsc should not throw any errors since its resolving from npm.

B) Change your tsconfig.json and map angular to the jspm path. For example

```
"baseUrl": ".",
"paths": {
     "angular2/*": [
        "jspm_packages/npm/angular2@2.0.0-beta.7/*"
     ],
     "rxjs/*": [
        "jspm_packages/npm/rxjs@5.0.0-beta.2/*"
     ]
  }
```

See https://github.com/frankwallis/plugin-typescript/tree/master/examples/angular2 for a full example.

Note that "baseUrl" and "paths" are not official properties and only on the beta version of typescript compiler.

The issue is currently being tracked here:
https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6012

Comment: I found this too hard, as also intellij does not recognize the path option yet. I do it the other way around and point jspm to node_modules